# Accessing elements inside ng-template

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popupTemplate">                                             
<div id="myPopup">                   
            <input type="checkbox" name="backup"/><label for="backup">Backup</label>
</div>
</script>
```

I want to access the popup div from outside script for adding more check boxes dynamically. I tried using jQuery `$("#myPopup")` but it is not accessing the element. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you need to post the rest of your code that shows how the popup is displayed.

Comment: I would suggest using [Angular Bootstrap UI $modal service](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template written inside `<script type="text/ng-template"></script>` will be stored in `$templateCache` with the given id. 
Retrieve the template in your controller using -- `$templateCache.get('popupTemplate')` 
Update it. 
Add it back to the `$templateCache` using -- `$templateCache.put('popupTemplate', '__updatedContent__')`