# accessing element by id inside ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I want to access

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="one.tpl.html">
  <div id="chart_div" ></div>
</script>
```

for my google graph api as

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

i'm getting "container not found" error.
Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712122/accessing-elements-inside-ng-template

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301475/call-angularjs-from-other-scripts/31301533#31301533

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular.element

```
    angular.element(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

or

```
   angular.element(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```